# How to fix this Primary key compromise that allow duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose to have two entities

```
Manager       Area
-------       -------
id            department
name          office 
id_area >>>>> id
```

They are in relation many to one. So that an office in a particular department can have more than one manager, but one manager can only be assigned to one office in a particular department.

So I should have "department + office" in AREA as primary key in order to avoid duplicates.

But I need an ID to link the two tables so the primary key in AREA becomes now just Area.ID. But this means I could end up with:

```
AREA
---------------------
ID    DEP.   OFFICE
---------------------
1      R       2
2      R       2
```

That shouldn't be possible!

How would you refactor this relationship in order to have no duplicates in AREA?

Answer (score 4):

Make `Area ID` the PK of the Area table AND add a seperate unique index on the combination of department and office.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `Area` ADD UNIQUE(`department`, `office`)
```

It's just like a primary key, except that it accepts `NULL` values and you can have more than one inside a table.